# Undefined not a function in datepicker

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

I am using this code, and have defined all the css and js. Even though this error comes..
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you loaded the datepicker module before running this code? If so try running this in `$(document).ready(function(){ //code here });`

Comment: please show your html also

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320361/datepicker-function-undefined-error?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should have the following links to the `jquery-ui` , `jquery-css` and the `jquery-api` :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Your HTML *could* be :

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Your script *should* be if you are calling the `datepicker()` function via `id` :

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
      });
</script>
```

OR if you want to invoke it via the *class* name , it should be :

```
<script>
      $(function() {
      $(".yourClassName").datepicker();
  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank You Abhishek. But, still not working bhai. Samethimes it work, sometimes not. WHat may be the reason behind it.?? can you clarify it.

Thank You

Comment: the reference to the jquery api could be spoilt , try taking the latest one